# Absolutely positioned element in a different position in Chrome than other browsers

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have an image/link that I'm trying to absolutely position with the following:

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <a href="/calendar"><img id="calendar" src="/bundles/majorproductionsadisite/images/calendar.jpg" alt="calendar" /></a>

    <div class="blogEntry">
        <h2>Blog title</h2>

        <div>Blog text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#calendar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 210px;
    left: 420px;
    z-index: 9000;
}
```

In Chrome, this puts the calendar image flush to the left of the blog:

[image: Chrome]

In contrast, in Firefox and IE, the calendar is positioned much further to the left:

[image: Firefox]

[image: IE]

Any suggestions on how I can get either Chrome to fall in line with the other two, or vice versa?

Comment: did you try to position relative parent ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a common reference point on the page for the absolutely positioned element.  Otherwise, the element is positioned relative to the browser window, so the position can change depending on the browser size, etc.  Try positioning the content div relatively.

http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using a CSS reset to zero out all of your margins and paddings? Resets are meant to prevent cross-browser differences as much as possible.

[Why Use CSS Resets](http://www.cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/)

Comment: Yes, I'm using a reset.

Comment: There may be something in another part of your code that is messing with your positioning. I would suggest using the browser developer tools (if none of the above suggestions work for you) to see if there is a setting on another element that is affecting your positioning.